# SEH Exceptions faulting my programs logic?

Tags: c

**INFORMATION**

My c++ program has no whole program optimization, has a Multi-Byte Character Set, and has enabled C++ Exceptions with SEH Exceptions (/EHa).

The following code reads information and then uses the read information in a simple math equation to determine the outcome.

**PROBLEM**

Here is an example to the situation that occurs!

For argument sake, underneath will show predetermined integer values, then the logic when the code is executed with these values.

healthalert = 19;

healthpercentage = 0; // THE PROBLEM IS HERE

health = 840;

fixedhealth = 840; // THIS SHOULD BE 885 AND NOT 840; IT IS 840 DUE TO HEALTHPERCENTAGE BEING 0 WHEN IT SHOULDN'T BE!

So in the first line of code determining the value of healthalert, the value is set to 19.

HOWEVER, when the equation for healthpercentage is calculated, even though healthalert is set to 19, the outcome for healthpercentage is zero?!?!?!?!!? WHY is this?

The next line is then executed and the value of health is 840.

Lastly, the value of fixedhealth is also 840; however, this should not be the case as it should be around 885. The reason fixedhealth is 840 is due to the math equation for healthpercentage outcoming to 0 when it shouldn't be!

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't give the variable types, but I'll bet they are integers. In that case, you're doing integer division, which truncates any fractional portion.

```
healthpercentage = (20 - healthalert) / healthalert * 100;
healthpercentage = (20 - 19) / 19 * 100;
healthpercentage = (int)(1 / 19) * 100;
healthpercentage = 0 * 100;
healthpercentage = 0;
```

If you want to continue to use integers, reorder operations so the multiplication is first:

```
healthpercentage = (20 - healthalert) * 100 / healthalert;
healthpercentage = (20 - 19) * 100 / 19;
healthpercentage = 1 * 100 / 19;
healthpercentage = (int)(100 / 19);
healthpercentage = 5;
```

Of course, even with this, the numbers don't match what you specified, so I don't understand your math. Perhaps this will still set you on the right track, however.

Answer (score 2):

You mention SEH exceptions, but it looks like a simple case of integer division to me. You say healthalert is 19. Therefore 20 - healthalert is 1. Therefore, (20 - healthAlert)/20 is *zero*, because all the numbers involved are integers. Change that 20 to a 20.0, then cast back to an int at the end, and you should be fine.

Edit: Or do what Dark Falcon suggested seconds before I hit submit. :)